# How to convert a tuple (in place) to first item in list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have boiler plate code that performs my sql queries and returns results (this is based off of working code written years ago by someone else).  Generally, that code will return a list of tuples, which is totally fine for what I need.

However, if there's only one result, the code returns a single tuple instead, and breaks code that expects to loop through a list of tuples.

I need any easy way to convert the tuple into the first item of a list, so I can use it in my code expecting to loop through lists.

What's the most straightforward way to do this in a single line of code?

Comment: Sidenote: you should fix this in the boilerplate code, not the code calling it!

Comment: This is maybe  true. However, boilerplate code is probably a misnomer -- it's a method from a utility class that the previous programmer created for their db work. As far as I know, some of their code may actually be dependent on getting back single tuples when they're expecting a single record response.

Comment: Ah, that is a problem! You could always wrap the function when used in your own code, though, rather than have this workaround duplicated throughout.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: not a bad idea. If I switch libraries, I may get something back that's not technically a list but a custom framework sequence, and my code might break...

Answer (score 0):

I figured there must be a straightforward way to do this, and there is. If my result set is called `rows`:

```
if not isinstance(rows,list):
    rows = [rows]
```

I don't know if this is the most Pythonic construction, or if there's a way of combining the `isintance` and `rows = [rows]` lines into a single statement.

Comment: `rows = rows if isinstance(rows, list) else [rows]`?

Comment: Sounds like that boilerplate code has a bug and you should fix it. If it cant be fixed, what you have is fine. But prioritize fixes over awkward workarounds.

Comment: @jonsharpe -- I was just about to add this myself!

Comment: @Shashank -- see my comment above. I'll eventually be replacing the boilerplate code with the built-in db functionality of a web framework, e.g. DJango or SQL Alchemy.